# Shell scripting - split xml into multiple files

Tags: xml, linux, shell, unix, awk

Am trying to split a big xml file into multiple files, and have used the following code in AWK script.

```
/<fileItem>/ {
        rfile="fileItem" count ".xml"
        print "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" > rfile
        print $0 > rfile
        getline
        while ($0 !~ "<\/fileItem>" ) {
                print > rfile
                getline
        }
        print $0 > rfile
        close(rfile)
        count++
}
```

The code above generates a list of xml files whose names read "fileItem_1", "fileItem_2", "fileItem3", etc.

However, I would like the file name to be something like "item_XXXXX" where the XXXXX is a node inside the XML - depicted as below

```
<fileItem>
<id>12345</id>
<name>XXXXX</name>
</fileItem>
```

So, basically I want the "id" node to be the filename.
Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Sounds like you should really be using a proper XML tool for this.  If your input is completely regular, using Awk to read a record at a time into memory and flushing it to disk when you reach its end tag (or end of file, though that violates XML) would probably allow you to do what you want.  Briefly, set a variable to 1 when you see the start tag, then while the variable is true, accumulate lines into another variable; finally, when you see the end tag, write out the accumulated lines and set the variable back to 0. This is a very standard Awk technique so examples should not be hard to find

Comment: If you're ever considering using `getline` in a script then make sure you read and fully understand http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline first so you know what you're getting into.

Comment: For future readers, A general solution's a lot more complicated than a `awk` command .... use XML tool for this, High-level languages with XML libraries, XSLT V2.0 with result-document, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not use `getline`. (I even read in an AWK book that it is not recommended to use it.) I think, using global variables for state it is even simpler. (Expressions with global variables may be used in patterns too.)

The script could look like this:

`test-split-xml.awk`:

```
/<fileItem>/ {
  collect = 1 ; buffer = "" ; file = "fileItem_"count".xml"
  ++count
}

collect > 0 {
  if (buffer != "") buffer = buffer"\n"
  buffer = buffer $0
}

collect > 0 && /<name>.+<\/name>/ {
  # cut "...<name>"
  i = index($0, "<name>") ; file = substr($0, i + 6)
  # cut "</name>..."
  i = index(file, "</name>") ; file = substr(file, 1, i - 1)
  file = file".xml"
}

/<\/fileItem>/ {
  collect = 0;
  print file
  print "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" >file
  print buffer >file
}
```

I prepared some sample data for a small test:

`test-split-xml.xml`:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<top>
  <some>
    <fileItem>
      <id>1</id>
      <name>X1</name>
    </fileItem>
  </some>
  <fileItem>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>X2</name>
  </fileItem>
  <fileItem>
    <id>2</id>
    <!--name>X2</name-->
  </fileItem>
  <any> other input </any>
</top>
```

... and got the following output:

```
$ awk -f test-split-xml.awk test-split-xml.xml
X1.xml
X2.xml
fileItem_2.xml

$ more X1.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <fileItem>
      <id>1</id>
      <name>X1</name>
    </fileItem>

$ more X2.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <fileItem>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>X2</name>
  </fileItem>

$ more fileItem_2.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <fileItem>
    <id>2</id>
    <!--name>X2</name-->
  </fileItem>

$
```

The comment of tripleee is reasonable. Thus, such processing should be limited to personal usage because different (and legal) formattings of XML files could cause errors in this script processing.

As you will notice, there is no `next` in the whole script. This is intentionally.

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost - you need a parser for this.

XML is a contextual data format. Regular expressions are not. So you can *never* make a regular expression base processing system actually work properly.

It's [just bad news](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

But parsers do exist, and they're quite easy to work with. I can give you a better example with a better data input. But I would use [`XML::Twig`](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig/) and `perl` to do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;


#subroutine to extract and process the item
sub save_item {
   my ( $twig, $item ) = @_;
   #retrieve the id
   my $id = $item -> first_child_text('id'); 
   print "Got ID of $id\n";

   #create a new XML document for output. 
   my $new_xml = XML::Twig -> new;
   $new_xml -> set_root (XML::Twig::Elt -> new ( 'root' ));

   #cut and paste the item from the 'old' doc into the 'new'  
   #note - "cut" applies to in memory, 
   #not the 'on disk' copy. 
   $item -> cut;
   $item -> paste ( $new_xml -> root );

   #set XML params (not strictly needed but good style)
   $new_xml -> set_encoding ('utf-8');
   $new_xml -> set_xml_version ('1.0');

   #set output formatting
   $new_xml -> set_pretty_print('indented_a');

   print "Generated new XML:\n";
   $new_xml -> print;

   #open a file for output
   open ( my $output, '>', "item_$id.xml" ) or warn $!;
   print {$output} $new_xml->sprint;
   close ( $output ); 
}

#create a parser. 
my $twig = XML::Twig -> new ( twig_handlers => { 'fileItem' => \&save_item } );
#run this parser on the __DATA__ filehandle below.
#you probably want parsefile('some_file.xml') instead. 
   $twig -> parse ( \*DATA );


__DATA__
<xml>
<fileItem>
<id>12345</id>
<name>XXXXX</name>
</fileItem>
</xml>
```

With `XML::Twig` comes [`xml_split`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/tools/xml_split/xml_split) which may be suited to your needs

Answer (score 1):

If your XML is really that well formed and consistent then all you need is:

```
awk -F'[<>]' '
/<fileItem>/ { header="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" ORS $0; next }
/<id> { close(out); out="item_" $3; $0=header ORS $0 }
{ print > out }
' file
```

The above is untested of course since you didn't provide sample input/output for us to test a possible solution against.