# Replace text in XML multi line tags using sed

Tags: xml, sed

I am new to sed and having trouble finding and replacing multiline XML code between the XML tags by some XML code. Here is the sample for XML code

```
 <List>
   <User>
      <Id>1234</Id>
         <Info>
            <Id>11</Id>
         </Info>
    </User>
 </List>
```

I want to replace the XMl code between List tags to become ..

```
<List>
   <Replace>
     <Id> 223 <Id>
   </Replace>
 </List>
```

I used 
`sed "s/\(<Id>\).*\(<\/Id\)/\19999\2/" input.xml > output.xml` but its working for single line but not for multi line. The content between List tags may change and also it can be inline.. so cannot reply upon particular pattern but need to rely on just tags. Any help or pointers would be appreciated?

Comment: dont use regex to parse xml. see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200462/simplest-way-to-do-basic-xml-parsing-from-unix-command-line

Comment: Processing XML in bash/awk is not the best (i.e. most robust / most safe) way but may provide quick & dirty solutions for personal/debugging purposes. So, you might consider these Q/As: [SO: Get a block from an XML file using data from a source file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43642559/get-a-block-from-an-xml-file-using-data-from-a-source-file/43704602?s=1|0.0000#43704602), [SO: Shell scripting - split xml into multiple files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42625786/shell-scripting-split-xml-into-multiple-files/42626222?s=6|0.0000#42626222).

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to ignore Lynch's advice, this will do it but you will need to re-prettify it:

```
sed -e ':a;N;$!ba' -e 's#<List.*</List>#<List>\n<Replace>\n<Id> 223 <Id>\n</Replace>\n</List>#' input.xml > output.xml
```

It probably needs the GNU version of sed.